# How do i use a "xxx-bin.tar.gz" file in a maven dependency?

Tags: maven

i have some code that needs to work with the shibboleth codebase.  The manual install steps i do are to download the shibboleth-identityprovider-2.3.5-bin.tar.gz, then extract it and do some tweaking and adding some jars that i build.

I want to do this in a maven assembly phase.  However, since the binary has a "-bin" in it, i don't know what to specify in my pom.xml to download that file.  In my pom i have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.internet2.middleware</groupId>
    <artifactId>shibboleth-identityprovider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5</version>
    <type>tar.gz</type>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>shibboleth-jce</artifactId>
            <groupId>edu.internet2.middleware</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

However, the dependency check fails (presumably because the tar file is named "shibboleth-identityprovider-2.3.5-bin.tar.gz" and not "shibboleth-identityprovier-2.3.5.tar.gz".

I'm not sure what i need to specify in my pom to use the proper tar file.

Comment: Add `<classifier>bin<classifier>` to your `<dependency>`.